# .NET separate backend and WebAPI or not

Tags: .net, api, structure, asp.net-core-webapi

I am fairly new to .NET and I need to do a project that provides a web interface for messages.

The question is:

- Should I separate the backend and the WebAPI?

**So should I create a .NET Core Console Application for the Backend and one .NET Core WebAPI for the API and so the backend will communicate with the API to store and read from DB.**

OR

**Should I create a .NET Core WebAPI Project that contains both (Backend and API)?**

The Backend will do background tasks (Message handling etc.)

If I do not separate (so put everything in .NET Core WebAPI), how should I create Background Thread that runs as long as the app runs?

(I do not want to use HangFire or Quartz)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should seperate the projects since there are so many use case differences.

An API endpoint, for example, often is designed to deliver loads of data from an endpoint while the same data access from a web application most likely will be more restricted and filtered. Also you while most likely have different authorization concepts to use for api (JWT Token f.e.) or web application backend (Basic User Authentication).

Further developments and maintenance will be much easier if you seperate the services also because you can always garantuee not to have dependencies between each other.

You also have much more reuseablitiy as well due to the fact that you are able to deliver either both services or only one of both.

Comment: So that means you would create one Console App for the Backend, one WebAPI Project for the API (that communicates with the DB) and one WebApp for the Frontend/Webpage?

One more question: Will the console application only communicate with the DB over the Rest API or does it not matter if the Console app has a connection to the DB as well?

Comment: I'd create two .net core services. One regular api service and one mvc .net core service providing also the web applications frontend views. Both services would share a database communication layer within a shared project using entity framework.

Comment: And how do you create this shared db communication layer ? 
And the API Service would also perform the background tasks ?

Comment: Or let's say I have my Solution in VS, which projects would it contain? 
- .NET Core WebApi (For the Backgroundtasks and the API)
- .NET Core WebApp (For the WebInterface)
- .... (for the Data access layer) ?

Comment: Yes, if the tasks differ (what they most likely will). To be more concrete about the communication layer: I'd create an interface for my database context which is implemented by my actual implementation of the communication layer. With this design the database context can be injected within both services. 

You could also do the same for shared background tasks.

Comment: F.e.: Lets call your project "WebTask" 

Solution would contain something like this:
- .Net Core Service -> WebTask.Api = API endpoints
- .Net Core Service -> WebTask.WebApplication = Web application
- Shared .Net Standard Class Library -> WebTask.DbContext = Database context
- Shared .Net Standard Class Library -> WebTask.SharedClasses = Shared stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202628/discussion-between-epanalepsis-and-bribi).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, most people will advise you to keep those separate as it's in line with the trendy microservices-based approach and gives you better flexibility in the future.

However, there might be scenarios when you could use a single WebAPI project with additional IHostedService(s) for processing messages and executing other background work. Please have a look at [this article for more info on IHostedService / BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice). I would go this way if the logic is quite similar for the API and messaging service or one is only a small addition for another.

A simple example of the latter would be a use case when a call to endpoint triggers some long running operation and then there is a message sent to the queue when it completes. You might want to separate those in case you plan to scale them separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So if I would separate API and backend, would I only communicate over the API with the DB or should I have one DB connection from the API to the DB and another one from the Backend to the DB?

Comment: @bribi If you are going to have microservices, each of them should have its own DB connection. They might share the same DB, but there are scenarios when each microservice has its own DB.